# Resize array generated by the loop

Tags: fortran, dynamic-arrays, fortran95

Let's have an array A(:,:)

```
Real, Allocatable:: A(:,:), B(:) 
Integer, Allocatable:: rowin(:) 
Integer:: m,j,k, nl

Allocate(A(max1,max2))
```

defined by several loops over m,j,k

```
 nl = 0

 A(rowin(m)+j,k) = ...
```

and now I want to select subset of A(:,:) such that their values are negative and store them into array B(:) unknown length yet, i.e.

```
if(A(rowin(m)+j,k).lt.0.d0) then
  nl = nl + 1
  B(nl) = A(rowin(m)+j,k)               
end if
```

Since max1 and max2 are very large numbers, I don't want to allocate B(:) of the length max1*max2, but exactly of the length that A(:,:) contains negative values. Also, I don't want to go through complicated loops over m,j and k again. 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you really require Fortran 90 or 95 or do you allow Fortran 2003 (the automatic re-allocation the answers use is from Fortran 2003 and is very useful).

Comment: Both are possible (prefer Fortran 90/95), but need to deal with loops and indices as @roygvib presented his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If pre-allocation of `B` to some fixed size is not desirable, we can emulate a dynamic array by using automatic reallocation of an allocatable array. In the simplest case, we can expand `B` element-by-element by adding a new value. For example, suppose that we have double loops over `m` and `j`, select values that match a given condition, and add tho values to `B`. Here, the size of `B` grows from 0, 1, 2, ... automatically.

```
integer, allocatable :: B(:)
integer :: m, j

allocate( B( 0 ) ) !! start from an empty array

do m = 1, 10000
do j = 1, 10000

    !! Some condition to add an element, e.g.
    if ( m == j .and. mod( m, 1000 ) == 0 ) then

        !! Add a new element to B.
        B = [ B, m ]
    endif
enddo
enddo

print *, "size( B ) = ", size( B )
print *, B(:)
```

The result becomes

```
size( B ) =  10
1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000
```

In your case you can probably add desired values of `A` in a similar way, for example

```
allocate( B( 0 ) )

do m = 1, ...
do j = 1, ...
do k = 1, ...
    if ( A( rowin(m)+j, k ) < 0.d0 ) then   !! or any condition
        B = [ B, A(rowin(m)+j,k) ]
    end if
enddo
enddo
enddo
```

---

A drawback of this approach is that it is very inefficient because `B` is re-allocated every time a new element is added. Although this is no problem for small `B`, it may become a serious bottleneck for large `B`. In this case one can increase the size of `B` geometrically rather than increasing by 1. For example, the following code doubles the size of `B` as needed so as to decrease the number of reallocation.

```
integer, allocatable :: B(:)
integer :: m, j, nl, p

allocate( B( 0 ) ) !! start from an empty array
nl = 0             !! number of elements found

do m = 1, 10000
do j = 1, 10000

    if ( m == j .and. mod( m, 1000 ) == 0 ) then

        nl = nl + 1

        !! Expand B if the size becomes insufficient.
        if ( size(B) < nl ) B = [ B, ( 0, p=1,nl ) ]

        !! Add a new value.
        B( nl ) = m 
    endif
enddo
enddo

B = B( 1 : nl )  !! adjust B to the optimal size
```

Some more notes:

- If a similar approach is used very often, it is convenient to write a utility routine like `resize()` that takes an allocatable array as an argument and changes its size. If the efficiency truly matters, it may be better to use `allocate()` and `move_alloc()` explicitly in `resize()` to eliminate one temporary array.
- The above code needs relatively new compilers that supports automatic reallocation of allocatable arrays in the left-hand side.
- If you use Intel fortran, it is necessary to add the `-assume realloc_lhs` option. If the size of `B` can become rather large, you will also need `-heap-arrays` option. For gfortran or Oracle fortran, no special options are necessary.
- We should *not* attach colon in the left-hand side; i.e., `B(:) = [ B, m ]` is NG
- For more details about dynamic arrays (e.g., growth rate), please see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) page.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly straightforward:

```
b = pack(a,a<0.0)
```

will pack the negative elements of `a` into the rank-1 array `b`.  With a recent compiler `b` will be automatically allocated to the correct size during the assignment.

(The latest Fortran standard gives a very similar operation as an example in the documentation of the `pack` function.)